# Jenkins (windows) on AWS works fine on localhost:8080, but not reachable from outside

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, jenkins, port

I installed Jenkins on an AWS instance along Apache (Bitnami WAMP stack) on a windows machine

Apache works great and can be contacted under `http://locahost` internally and `http://x.x.x.x` (my own IP) externally

Jenkins works great under `http://locahost:8080` internally **but does not work with** `http://x.x.x.x:8080` externally

I have opened an inbound TCP rule for port 8080 on the security group on AWS

I opened the jenkins.xml config and launched it each time with following parameters

```
--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0
--httpListenAddress=x.x.x.x
```

I read that i should change the $HTTP_HOST variable, but not sure where i should do that on a windows machine

This is really frustrating me

Answer (score 2):

Check the windows firewall configuration on the server. Usually Windows denies external access by default. 
Check this for firewall configuration : http://www.codepuppet.com/2014/02/08/enabling-external-access-to-your-apache-web-server-on-windows-7/